# Microsoft Outlook on PC does not update calendar via iCal link (google calendar) but does on iPhone

Tags: outlook

so this is a real brain buster. I have searched and tried every different setting there is.

For some reason, my google calendar adds updates in via my outlook on my iPhone, and via the google calendar app, but when I type in a new appointment on my computer and hit update, it erases all of the appointments I put in on my computer and downloads them from the server.

I have done the following:

I added in 4 different types of calendar, with

1. http://(googleaddress/private).ics
2. webcal://(googleaddress/private).ics
3. http://(googleaddress/public).ics
4. webcal://(googleaddress/public).ics

I even tried contacting Microsoft's support, and they told me it was impossible that my iPhone was updating the google calendar, as it is not supported. The support person refused to acknowledge that my phone was in fact updating my calendar, and they claimed it was my other exchange account doing it. However that makes no sense, as I removed my other Exchange email account to make sure that was not happening, and it surely was not.

So my question, why in the world would Outlook the IOS app be able to update my google calendar perfectly, but my PC cannot? I am pretty sure I saw some add-ins online that I could use to do this, but I was trying to do it without downloading more software. The fact that my phone can do it and my computer cannot is really irritating to me, both using Microsoft Outlook.

Thank you in advance guys.

Corey

Comment: Also, I think google has changed their OAuth protocol. I found a few plugins that work inside outlook, but they are waiting to get their apps approved by google. The best plugin I found that is free is "CalDav Synchronizer "but they are waiting on approval from google at the moment. This seems to be the best workaround so far. The next solution I have found is a program called "Outlook Google Calendar Sync", but it has to be running along side outlook at the same time.

Comment: Also, I think google has changed their OAuth protocol. I found a few plugins that work inside outlook, but they are waiting to get their apps approved by google. The best plugin I found that is free is "CalDav Synchronizer "but they are waiting on approval from google at the moment. This seems to be the best workaround so far. The next solution I have found is a program called "Outlook Google Calendar Sync", but it has to be running along side outlook at the same time. This is less than ideal, as it becomes a race situation, but I am tinkering with the settings to get it working MUCH better.